# How to optimize performance of Time-Trigger Azure Function in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure-functions, task-parallel-library, azure-function-async

I have a time-triggered Azure Function that runs every SECOND. The function reads data from API Servers and stores it into ADLS. How can I optimize the performance of the function so that it can make more that 500 API calls and store per second data for each call in a SECOND.

```
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/1 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");


            log.LogInformation($"Execution starts at: {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff")}");

            try
            {
                var IDs = GetIDs(); //makes 1 API call to fetch list of IDs
                
                foreach(var i in IDs){
                   ReadAndWriteData(i); //reads data for each ID from API server and stores in ADLS
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.LogError($"An exception has been raised : {e}");
            }

            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function execution ended at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
       
        public static async Task<List<string>> GetIDs(){
          //List<string> idList = await Task.Run(()=> ReadIDs()); //makes 1 API call to fetch list of IDs
          //return idList;
        }
       public static async Task ReadAndWriteData(String id){
           //var result = await Task.Run(()=> ReadData()); //reads data for each ID from API server
           ...
           // uploads data to ADLS 
       }
```

What is the best possible way to get data accurately for all IDs per second? I have tried some parallel programming/ TPL methods but still it is giving expected accuracy if I use only one ID, not for all.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. What is the relation between an ID and time?

Comment: while I also don't understand what your actual problem is, your code just looks wrong. E.g. `var IDs = GetIDs();` You are making a non-awaited call to an async method - and then trying to use the result in the foreach loop. that just does not work like that.

Comment: Hi @Magnus, I need to fetch data for all IDs every second. Let me try to make it more clear. Let's forget about ID and consider we have to call ** ReadAndWriteData(i)**, where i is just a list of strings like {"1","2",..."500"}. If this list has 2,3 values I am getting data for every second and uploading it in ADLS in following storage hierarchy yyyy/mm/dd/H/M/S/file.json. 
But for 500 values, I can see in every minute's folder only 1 folder gets created for a second, not for all 60 secs.
Hope, this helps understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there can be many issues that are causing performance problems to you. You have to debug using [Azure Service Profiler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/exploring-the-azure-service-profiler/) **or any other tool** and check which line of code is taking how much time.

Some of the reasons can be:

1. There is **inefficient** algorithm written for fetching IDs/ADLS operations.
2. You have not added `.ConfigureAwait(false)` along with `await`.
3. `Automatic scaling` is not enabled for `Azure Functions` and scaling is hampered due to insufficient `manual scaling`.
4. You are using heavy Nuget packages which take a lot of time to create an instance of Azure Functions.
5. You have not made `ReadIDs` and `ReadData` functions as [asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Hey, @singhh-msft. Thanks for your suggestions. 
1. Though the function doesn't have much scope for optimization. I will still take a look at it.
2. Added `ConfigureAwait(false)` along with await, but didn't make much difference.
3. How can I enable Automatic scaling for Azure Function?
4. _Energistics_ is the only Nuget package that I am using apart from the common ones like NewtonSoft.Json, since I am working with WITSML data.
5. All functions are async.

Comment: 3. Scaling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#scale;  5. Function definition should have `Task` in return type and `async` keyword. pls make sure this is there. For rest points: okay

Comment: In my scenario, using Consumption Plan for function app should improve the performance right? As it has max 200 instances. Is there anything I need to configure to ensure that max instances are used?

Comment: It depends on the load you are giving.